# How to create a GraphServiceClient using token to access Microsoft Graph Service using Managed Service Identity (MSI)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, .net-7.0

I have a asp.net core 3.1 application which uses nuget package Microsoft.Graph 4.0.0.

I used the below code to generate an instance of GraphServiceClient:

```
private async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphServiceClientUsingMSIAsync()
{
    var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenForMicrosoftGraphUsingMSIAsync();
    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((req) =>
    {
        req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(C.Constants.Bearer, accessToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }));
    return graphServiceClient;
}
```

using the above GraphServiceClient I was able to pull user details as shown in the below code :

```
private async Task<User> GetUserFromMicrosoftGraphAsync(string email, User user, string cacheKey)
{
    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>{new QueryOption("$select", "id,userPrincipalName,mail,displayName,surname,givenname,officeLocation,usertype"), new QueryOption("$filter", $"mail eq '{email}' or userPrincipalName eq '{email}'")};
    var graphClient = await GetGraphServiceClientUsingMSIAsync();
    var userDetails = await graphClient.Users.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
    user = userDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserType != Constants.Guest);
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.UserPrincipalName = (user.Mail ??= user.UserPrincipalName).ToLower();
        user.Mail = user.Mail.ToLower();
        _cacheProvider.Set(cacheKey, user, C.CacheGroups.Graph);
    }

    return user;
}
```

Recently I have been trying to migrate this code to .NET7 with nuget package Microsoft.Graph 5.12.0

I came across few docs :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/multi-service-web-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-powershell%2Cprogramming-language-csharp

https://damienbod.com/2023/01/16/implementing-secure-microsoft-graph-application-clients-in-asp-net-core/

and then created the below method :

```
   private async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphServiceClientUsingMSIAsync()
{
    if (_graphServiceClient != null)
        return _graphServiceClient;
    string[] scopes = new[]{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"};
    var chainedTokenCredential = GetChainedTokenCredentials();
    _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(chainedTokenCredential, scopes);
    return _graphServiceClient;
}

private ChainedTokenCredential GetChainedTokenCredentials()
{
    if (!_environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        return new ChainedTokenCredential(new ManagedIdentityCredential());
    }
    else // dev env
    {
        var tenantId = _configuration["xxxxxx"];
        var clientId = _configuration["yyyyyy";
        var clientSecret = _configuration["aaaaa"];
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions{AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud};
        // https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
        var devClientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
        var chainedTokenCredential = new ChainedTokenCredential(devClientSecretCredential);
        return chainedTokenCredential;
    }
}

private async Task<User> GetUserFromMicrosoftGraphAsync(string email, User user, string cacheKey)
{
    var graphClient = await GetGraphServiceClientUsingMSIAsync();
    var filter = $"mail eq '{email}' or userPrincipalName eq '{email}'";
    var result = await graphClient.Users[filter].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[]{"id", "userPrincipalName", "mail", "displayName", "surname", "givenname", "officeLocation", "usertype"};
    });
    user = result;
    if (user is not null)
    {
        user.UserPrincipalName = (user.Mail ??= user.UserPrincipalName).ToLower();
        user.Mail = user.Mail.ToLower();
        _cacheProvider.Set(cacheKey, user, CacheGroups.Graph);
    }

    return user;
}

public async Task<User> GetUserAsync(string email)
{
    var cacheKey = FormatKey(CacheKeys.GraphUser, email);
    User user = _cacheProvider.Get<User>(cacheKey, CacheGroups.Graph);
    if (user is null)
    {
        user = await GetUserFromMicrosoftGraphAsync(email, user, cacheKey);
    }

    return user;
}
```

On invoking the method GetUserAsync() in my local Devlopment environment, with all the details I am getting the below error:

**Error Details:**

```
"InnerExceptions":[{"HResult":-2146233088,"Message":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.","Source":"Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary","TargetSite":"Void MoveNext()","AdditionalData":{},"BackingStore":{"ReturnOnlyChangedValues":false,"InitializationCompleted":true},"Error":{"AdditionalData":{"innerError":{"ValueKind":"Object","$type":"JsonElement"}},"BackingStore":{"ReturnOnlyChangedValues":false,"InitializationCompleted":true},"Code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","Details":null,"Innererror":null,"Message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","Target":null},"ResponseStatusCode":403,"Type":"Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError"}]
```

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Comment: When using GraphServiceClient created by your new method GetGraphServiceClientUsingMSIAsync() does the client throws any exception or return any error when trying to access data?

Comment: have you published your code to azure app service and test? using managed identity might require you to host the app in azure web app.

Comment: Right now I am working on my local development environment. Hence not sure how to validate it in this case.